# Probability of n-dimensional spheres in n-dimensional cubes?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a unit disk inside of a unit square, both centered at the origin.

Then, we assign a random point $p$ to the space inside the unit square, and it may or may not be in the circle. If it isn't, we repeat this scenario until it is. If it is, we move to a unit ball inside of a unit cube, and if the point lands in this, we move to a unit hyper-disk inside of a unit hyper-cube, and so forth. Of course if it isn't, you just repeat the trial until it is.

Suppose you quit the process after $n$ trials. What is the probability, in terms of $n$, of stopping on a level of at least $n-2$ dimensions?

Comment: Is there a unit circle inside of a unit square?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there's a closed form for this?

Comment: There is a unit circle centered at the origin, and there is a unit square centered at the origin

Comment: I would think so except I wonder how the fact that there are seperate formulae for the odd-dimensional spheres and even-dimensional spheres would mess things up...

Comment: The terms "disk" or "ball" are likely more apt than "circle" and "sphere" because the latter are commonly understood to be without interior.

Comment: @thecat What is your definition of unit circle and unit square?

Comment: The number of trials $N_n$ in dimension $n\geqslant2$ is geometric with parameter $v_n$ the volume of the $n$-dim unit ball and you are asking for $p_n=P(N_2+\cdots+N_{n-3}\leqslant n-1)$. There are $n-4$ random variables involved, all positive and integer valued and their sum should be at most $n-1$ hence at least $n-7$ of them are equal to $1$. Thus one can probably write $p_n$ as a veeeeery messy sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the volume of the $n$-sphere is $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2 + 1)}$, while the volume of the $n$-cube (with side length $1$) is $1$; so the volume of the $n$-cube with side length $2$ is $2^n$.

Comment: I don't think a "hint" is especially justified as an answer here.  The OP acknowledges the ratios of these $n$-volumes in the Comments under the Question, so a more helpful response would explain how the ratio values (probabilities of a single trial in dimension $n$) can be combined to solve the stated problem.

Comment: I considered the main cause of confusion to be "there are separate formulae for the odd-dimensional spheres and even-dimensional spheres". Giving a single formula may be helpful.

Comment: The unit $n$-ball is too big to fit inside the unit $n$-cube.